# unpivot MultiIndex DataFrame with pd.melt()

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to unpivot a DataFrame with MultiIndex columns, but I struggle to get the exact output I want. I played with all the parameters of the `pd.melt()` function but couldn't make it...

Here is the kind of input I have :

```
import pandas as pd
indexes = [['TC1', 'TC2'], ['x', 'z', 'Temp']]
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(indexes))

data.loc[0,('TC1', 'x')] = 10
data.loc[0,('TC1', 'z')] = 100
data.loc[0,('TC1', 'Temp')] = 250
data.loc[0,('TC2', 'x')] = 20
data.loc[0,('TC2', 'z')] = 200
data.loc[0,('TC2', 'Temp')] = 255
```

And here is the kind of output I would like, with "Time" column being the index of data

```
  Time   TC   x    z Temp
0    0  TC1  10  100  250
1    0  TC2  20  200  255
```

My real data have far more columns of kind `TCx`.
Any clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try

```
data_out = data.stack(level=0).rename_axis(['Time','TC']).reset_index()

Out[87]:
   Time   TC Temp   x    z
0     0  TC1  250  10  100
1     0  TC2  255  20  200
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
data.stack(0).reset_index().rename(
    columns={'level_0': 'Time', 'level_1': 'TC'})
```

So in this case `.stack()` is what you need:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html